# Service Layer e BLL são a mesma coisa?

Tags: c#, arquitetura-de-software

Tenho dúvida sobre `service Layer` e `BLL`, qual a diferença? onde é usada?

Gostaria de exemplo de `classes` usando essas estrutura.

Answer (score 3):

A BLL corresponde à camada de negócio, ou seja, onde deve ficar as regras do seu negócio, a "inteligência" dele. Já a Service Layer (camada de serviço), se entende  como uma plataforma de serviços disponíveis, como por exemplo, web services dos Correios, com "serviços" como o de fornecer informações de rastreamento de uma encomenda ou consulta de CEP. O que será "exposto" serão serviços, mas cada um deles tem a sua inteligência, suas regras, suas validações, etc.

Então respondendo sua pergunta: não, BLL e Service Layer não são a mesma coisa, porém estão ligadas.

Comment: Oi, Luiz, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Removi as saudações do seu post pois são consideradas ruído. Confira porque este site é diferente dos fóruns tradicionais fazendo o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Ambos são complementares. Business layer é relacionado à lógica de sua aplicação(validação e processamento de informaçãoes, por exemplo). Service Layer é a camada onde você pode consumir ou fornecer serviços(dados) com outros sistemas.